# How do I ascertain that my gems are secure?

Tags: ruby, security, rubygems

I'm looking for an automated way to check all the gems used in my sinatra-based site for available security updates. Does such a thing exist?

My principle attitude to updates is: If it ain't broke, don't try to fix it. But if I am vulnerable then I want to know about it. By only applying security updates, I keep the amount of potential behaviour change to a minimum.

Background: The majority of my previous work has been in Drupal. In that community, maintainers can tag their module releases as fixing security issues. That means that my website, or my CLI tools, can query release data for modules used in the current website to see whether security updates are available and notify me.

Comment: [CodeClimate](https://codeclimate.com/) might help because it also does security reviews. But I don't know that it will review your gem versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [bundle-audit gem](https://github.com/rubysec/bundler-audit) from rubysec on github. Run it periodically/routinely. It's free, is kept up to date via the CVE library of known security threats, and reports which gems in your project have available updates.

Comment: I'm no longer working with Ruby except for small scripts where this issue is not critical, however, I had a look the github page yo link to and it looks like exactly what I wanted when I originally asked this question. It also looks active so I so I have changed this to the accepted answer. Thanks for resurrecting this question.

Comment: Thanks for keeping SO up-to-date. Since I wrote this, I've learned that  many cloud services including CodeClimate make available bundle-audit as a plug-in.

Answer (score 6):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no definitive way to automate this.  There's no notion of a flag in Ruby gems indicating that they are security updates, etc.  Most gem maintainers are pretty good about honoring the convention of `major.minor.patch` for version numbers, though.  Major bumps are API-breaking, minor add functionality but are backwards compatible, and patch are for bugfixes or very trivial changes.  There's nothing enforcing this, and some gems don't even use the three-part version numbers.  Rails itself is particularly egregious about failing here; Rails minor version bumps are universally non-compatible, breaking changes.  Rails patch bumps tend to be security fixes, though.

If this is sufficient for your needs, you can use Bundler to specify that you only want patch-level updates:

```
gem 'foo', '~> 2.2.0'
```

...will install the latest patch level of version 2.2.x of the gem (e.g. you might end up with 2.2.12, but not 2.3.0).

See [the Rubygems docs](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74) for more about version strings (used by Bundler), and how to be conservative ("pessimistic" in their terminology).  Also see their [numbering guidelines](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/7).  Again, bear in mind that these are not strictly enforced, and with Rails itself providing such a terrible example of breaking convention, other gem authors don't always do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. I'd actually got the impression that minor release version were expected to break existing codebase, which made wonder why major/minor were both necessary. It does make me very appreciative of the Drupal release system although that is not perfect either.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) with your project you can check that you are using the latest versions of gems with `bundle outdated`. To know if the version of a gem that you are using has a known security vulnerability, you can use the [bundler-audit](https://github.com/rubysec/bundler-audit) gem, or alternatively the [holepicker](https://github.com/jsuder/holepicker) gem. There is also a service called [Gemnasium](https://gemnasium.com/) that can monitor your gems for you and notify you when a gem is updated or has a security issue.

**Update**: Github now monitors your repository's `Gemfile` and notifies you when a gem has a security issue.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thankyou.

Comment: Please consider re-accepting my answer as the better answer. It is a [best practice for others that find this page later](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon). Thank you.

Comment: I'll definitely consider it but I would feel misleading if I did it now. By the time you answered, my work had drifted away from Ruby again so I never properly evaluated the tools you mentioned. I did check out Gemnasium more thoroughly but that was because of hauleth's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

There is website called [Gemnasium](https://gemnasium.com/). It check if gems that you are using are the newest one, and if there is any security issue it will send you email.

Comment: Thanks. If I were using GitHub for my customer sites then that would be pretty cool. I'm actually using BitBucket because of its unlimited private repos. However, the [FAQ page](https://gemnasium.com/questions) did turn me on to `bundle outdated` and [RubyGems webhooks](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/#webhook), both of which I'll want to look at.

Comment: Gemnasium customer services responded to my email asking about how they ascertain security status. Given the absence of a security_patch flag in gemspec files, their system sounds like as good as it gets. I'm now considering switching back to GitHub.